# Programmatically add a drop down list to a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how I can programmatically add a drop down list to a specific cell of an Excel worksheet using VBA, I would like to be able to add a drop down list to cells(i,j) for example and to define the elements of the list.

Comment: I've done some researches on the internet and I found some solutions but I don't find how to refer to the cell that will contain the drop down list with the indexes i and j : Cells(i,j)

Comment: Do you need a `Data Validation` dropdown, or do you need to include an `ActiveX ComboBox`

Comment: Sorry I don't know those terms, I just would like to add a drop down list to a cell to determine its value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### To do it programmatically :

```
With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Value1;Value2;Value3"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Where `Formula1` has the values in a list separated by `;`.

### Better way (dynamic named range)

If you have a dynamic list of records that you want to populate in a drop down then, define a named range using the following formula:

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;1;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1)`

..assuming that your data is in `Sheet1` with a header in the first row:

```
A1  Header
A2  Value1
A2  Value2
A3  Value3
```

Comment: Ok, so I have to do `Cells(i,j).Select` before you're code, right ?

Comment: Yes. Or just replace `Selection.Validation` with `Cells(i,j).Validation`

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks. There is just a small mistake : the values must be separated by `,`

Comment: Not a mistake actually :). You simply have difference `locale` than I do. Your list separator in Windows settings is a comma `,` (US style) and mine is a semicolon `;` (European style)

Comment: :-) Before I read down through the comments I had the same issue with ";" and ",". So what happens if I'm writing the code here in the US and someone in Europe goes to use my file? Would I have to write something to accommodate both regions?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to crack it!

```
Sub MyVlookUp()
    Const SpecialCharacters As String = " ,-,."
    Dim Str As String
    Dim newStr As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Dim SRng As Range
    Dim char As Variant
    Dim newSrchRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Sheets("VlookUp").Select
    Range("B7:GZ8000").Select
    Selection.ClearContents


    For i = 7 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Str = Worksheets("VlookUp").Cells(i, "A").Value
    newStr = Left(Str, 15)
    For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
    newStr = Replace(newStr, char, "")
    Next

    Worksheets("data").Activate
    Set SRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1", ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
    SRng.Copy Destination:=Range("E1:E7001")
    Set SrchRng = Range("E1:E7001")
    For Each newSrchRng In SrchRng.Cells
    For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
    newSrchRng.Value = Replace(newSrchRng.Value, char, "")
    Next
    Next

    Set c = SrchRng.Find(newStr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            Range(Cells(c.Row, 2), Cells(c.Row, 3)).Copy
            With Worksheets("VlookUp")
            .Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
            End With

            Set c = SrchRng.FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If


    Next i
    Worksheets("VlookUp").Activate

     SrchRng.Clear
End Sub
```